# (Ionic 2) Setting seconds in DateTime Component

Tags: ionic2, datetimepicker

How can I have a DateTime Component that displays seconds only, has a default value (image 1) and has an interval between options (image 2) 
as the example on: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/ (it´s the last datetime input, and its label is "Alert")

The images below come from the example link mentioned above and that's what I would like to achieve. The problem is the ionic documentation shows this example but doesn't show its code.

Image 1

[image: Image 1]

Image 2

[image: Image 2]

On my code I have this so far:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Alert</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="ss" [(ngModel)]="myAlert">
  </ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: can you update your question with code you have worked

Comment: I don't understand the question.  I see this image with 00,15,30.  How would you want to change that?

Comment: @PhilipBrack, I edited my question to explain better. These images are from example link, not what I already did.

Comment: @MohanGopi. I also edit my question with the code I have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the source code of that example you've posted?: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/demos/src/datetime/pages/page-one/page-one.html

You probably need something like this:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Alert</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="mm" minuteValues="0,15,30,45" [(ngModel)]="alertTime"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: This example is for minutes, is there a way to do same for seconds?

Comment: I checked and you cannot do for seconds.

Comment: @BrunoOrnelas Have you tried to change the displayFormat to "ss"?

Comment: @Gomes, yes it works. Is there a param like minuteValues related to seconds?

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention it. Try to use decimal minutes to represent seconds.